# Is it possible to convert game hair cards into hair particle systems?

Tags: particles, hair

I ask this question because I am trying to find a way to convert a collection of hair cards from a game into a particle hair system. I tried using the hairnet addon, but It wasn't working for me. I want the hair particles to grow from the hair cap. Below are pictures of the hair cards as a whole and a single one of the hair cards in edit mode if it helps.

[image: here is a screenshot of the hair cards that I wanna turn into hair particles]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to convert it to hair particles? They take a lot of time and generally aren't worth the trouble.

Comment: What exactly did not work with HairNet addon?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like that. Your only option is to delete all the hair cards and replace them with hair.

It isn't worth it. I would just say go with the hair cards and set all the hair card to any hair texture you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HairNet addon](https://github.com/Jandals/HairNet/releases) to convert hair cards to hair particles.

- the hair cards can be directly used as *Sheets* for the HairNet addon. They may need some preparation to fulfill a few requirements:

  - the sheets must have a mesh of quads. If the hair cards are made of tris you can convert them to quads with *Face → Tris To Quads* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), in *Edit* mode.
  - the hair cards need at least 3 vertical edges. A vertical edge will be converted to a hair guide (particle/strand). Add and apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier if needed or add some edge loops manually (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
  - all hair cards in one object must have the same number of vertical subdivisions. You can use the [Select Islands by Face Count](https://blenderartists.org/t/select-all-meshes-with-same-number-of-faces-in-edit-mode/1194005/3) addon by *Stan_Pancakes* to separate the hair cards into separate objects with *Separate By Face Count*
- if the hair cards fulfill these requirements you need to *Add Seams* to the edge that will be the root of the hair. With <kbd>L</kbd> you can select the hair cards and hide (<kbd>H</kbd>) them after you have added the seams. [image: marking the roots]
- use *Sheets* in the HairNet addon to create the particles.
- set children type to *Simple*

Don't forget to ["touch" the generated hair](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Objects/HairNet/) in comb mode as described in the addon.

**Note:** There is currently a bug that makes the particles of existing hair particle systems move down on the Z-axis. To prevent this just disable the viewport visibility (monitor icon) in the *Particle System Properties* or the *Modifier Properties* for all existing particle systems before you add another with the addon (Blender 2.9x and HairNet 0.6.x are affected).

Hair cards:
[image: hair cards]

Converted hair:
[image: hair particles]

Cyles render:
[image: Cycles render]