# What is the best way to convert modeled hair into realistic hair?

Tags: modeling, materials, particles, transforms, hair

I'm a beginner, does anyone familiar with the answer? I don't want to make custom hair all by myself.   I would like that already modeled hair to be transformed into realistic hair. So I don't have to groom the hair.  Make sure you add a picture/gif explanation to help me better understand and show how you make it so I can comprehend how to make it myself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a hair particle system?

Comment: First thing I think of is making a standard hair particle system, then somehow guiding it into the mesh. Idk how to do that.

Comment: the HairNet addon can do this. Either use the poly hair that you have and delete all horizontal edges and all faces, just keep the vertical edges. Then you can convert these "fibers" into hair particles. OR use snapping and create curves that you align along the poly hair. The curves can also be converted to hair particles with the addon. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/215438/107598. And here is a video: https://youtu.be/Km6QXlAkjZM